# Check if file exists on excel table using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, filesystems

I have a csv table full of file's path. I want to check for each row if file exists.

```
import csv
import os.path
import ntpath
import shutil

with open('C:\Test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in spamreader:
        print(', '.join(row))
        if os.path.exists(str(row)):
            print("Copy...")
```

Table's row example: c:\test\notfound.xlsx

I don't understand why my code is not working? When I set row with a fix path it's working just fine! row = "c:/test/notfound.xlsx"

Comment: it will be nice if we can see your csv file,Paste first few line of csv or share the same using git.

Comment: Solution FOUND! When converting from list (row) to string: `if os.path.exists(str(row)):` we get: ['c:/test/notfound.xlsx']. The right conversation is:  `str = ''.join(row)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this line is

```
c:\test\notfound.xlsx
```

\n is an escape character in python.
You need to escape your '\' as well.

I've tested this on my system

```
os.path.exists('C:\newfile.txt)
False

os.path.exists('C:\\newfile.txt)
True
```

Comment: If that is the real problem then you can use os.path.exists(r'C:\newfile.txt') where r win the prefix will take care of escape characters

Comment: This is not the problem. I changed the excel row to the path c://test//notfound.xlsx - but Still not working...  @VigneshKalai

Comment: @wizard could you provide the csv file data sample

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have used

```
if os.path.exists(str(row)):
```

which should be :

```
if os.path.exists(', '.join(row)):
```

because the row variable is in List format and using str() to convert it will just convert it into string without removing the parenthesis